# How to simulate rays emerging from an image/div to another image/div using HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to build a page to show a blown-up version of an image.

I have the smaller image and the bigger image built out. I am not sure how to build the in between portion that looks like rays coming out of the smaller image.

### HTML

```
<div class="flex">
    <div class="exp" tabindex="0">
        <img class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
    </div>
    <div class="big-image">
        <img class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x550">
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.exp {
    margin: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ded3c0;
    border-radius: 100%;
    line-height: 80px;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.exp .image {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
.big-image {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 19px;
}
.flex {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Any pointers on how to do this is helpful.

Here is jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/npkeq7ut/

Comment: explain clearly what you want bigger image coming means ?

Comment: Will the effect be dynamic; will the "blown-up" version show on user interaction; will it move or remain static; should the "rays" be solid, faded, colored, animated... ? Please provide greater detail.

Comment: yes, the blown up version will be shown on UI along with rays and small image all the time.. the rays portion should have grey background.. the wole thing should be responsive.

Comment: You asked for an answer using HTML and CSS but your accepted answer is done with javascript and that's not even a tag or an option in your question.

Comment: Hi @Rob, I thought my question was achievable by just HTML/CSS.  out of all the answers i got jacobs answer worked well for me. If there is a solution to my question using just HTML/CSS, I would be happy to change the accepted answer. I will make sure I will be careful next time while asking a question. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only lines you can achieve this with JS and skew transform:

```
let topLine = document.getElementById('top-line');
let bottomLine = document.getElementById('bottom-line');

function updateLines()
{   
  let b = document.getElementById('b').getBoundingClientRect();
  let a = document.getElementById('a').getBoundingClientRect();

  let left = a.right;
  let width = b.left - a.right;

  let tHeight = a.top - b.top;
  let tTop = tHeight / 2 + b.top;
  let tAngle = Math.atan(tHeight / width) * 180 / Math.PI;

  let bHeight = b.bottom - a.bottom;
  let bTop = bHeight / 2 + a.bottom - bottomLine.offsetHeight;
  let bAngle = Math.atan(bHeight / width) * 180 / Math.PI;

  topLine.style.top = tTop + "px";
  topLine.style.left = left + "px";
  topLine.style.width = width + "px";
  topLine.style.transform = "skewY("+(-tAngle)+"deg)";

  bottomLine.style.top = bTop + "px";
  bottomLine.style.left = left + "px";
  bottomLine.style.width = width + "px";
  bottomLine.style.transform = "skewY("+(bAngle)+"deg)";
}
updateLines();
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/JacobDesight/f40yeuqe/2/

@EDIT

If you want trapeze with background then here is example using canvas: https://jsfiddle.net/JacobDesight/f40yeuqe/3/

Comment: yes the background should be grey (I have updated the image).. Is there any example i can look at for perspective transformation or canvas to set trapeze bg (I am new to transformation or canvas). Thanks

Comment: @saga I've added an example with the background to my answer. Thought canvas will be slightly better than perspective. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks that helped.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a starting point for you.

Code by thecodeplayer. 
http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/magnifying-glass-for-images-using-jquery-and-css3

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var native_width = 0;
  var native_height = 0;

  //Now the mousemove function
  $(".magnify").mousemove(function(e) {
    //When the user hovers on the image, the script will first calculate
    //the native dimensions if they don't exist. Only after the native dimensions
    //are available, the script will show the zoomed version.
    if (!native_width && !native_height) {
      //This will create a new image object with the same image as that in .small
      //We cannot directly get the dimensions from .small because of the 
      //width specified to 200px in the html. To get the actual dimensions we have
      //created this image object.
      var image_object = new Image();
      image_object.src = $(".small").attr("src");

      //This code is wrapped in the .load function which is important.
      //width and height of the object would return 0 if accessed before 
      //the image gets loaded.
      native_width = image_object.width;
      native_height = image_object.height;
    } else {
      //x/y coordinates of the mouse
      //This is the position of .magnify with respect to the document.
      var magnify_offset = $(this).offset();
      //We will deduct the positions of .magnify from the mouse positions with
      //respect to the document to get the mouse positions with respect to the 
      //container(.magnify)
      var mx = e.pageX - magnify_offset.left;
      var my = e.pageY - magnify_offset.top;

      //Finally the code to fade out the glass if the mouse is outside the container
      if (mx < $(this).width() && my < $(this).height() && mx > 0 && my > 0) {
        $(".large").fadeIn(100);
      } else {
        $(".large").fadeOut(100);
      }
      if ($(".large").is(":visible")) {
        //The background position of .large will be changed according to the position
        //of the mouse over the .small image. So we will get the ratio of the pixel
        //under the mouse pointer with respect to the image and use that to position the 
        //large image inside the magnifying glass
        var rx = Math.round(mx / $(".small").width() * native_width - $(".large").width() / 2) * -1;
        var ry = Math.round(my / $(".small").height() * native_height - $(".large").height() / 2) * -1;
        var bgp = rx + "px " + ry + "px";

        //Time to move the magnifying glass with the mouse
        var px = mx - $(".large").width() / 2;
        var py = my - $(".large").height() / 2;
        //Now the glass moves with the mouse
        //The logic is to deduct half of the glass's width and height from the 
        //mouse coordinates to place it with its center at the mouse coordinates

        //If you hover on the image now, you should see the magnifying glass in action
        $(".large").css({
          left: px,
          top: py,
          backgroundPosition: bgp
        });
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```css
/*Some CSS*/
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.magnify {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
}

/*Lets create the magnifying glass*/

.large {
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  /*Multiple box shadows to achieve the glass effect*/
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 7px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85), 0 0 7px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 0 40px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  /*Lets load up the large image first*/
  background: url('http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/iphone.jpg') no-repeat;
  /*hide the glass by default*/
  display: none;
}

/*To solve overlap bug at the edges during magnification*/
.small {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Lets make a simple image magnifier -->
<div class="magnify">
 
<!-- This is the magnifying glass which will contain the original/large version -->
<div class="large"></div>
 
<!-- This is the small image -->
<img class="small" src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/iphone.jpg" width="200"/>
 
</div>

<!-- Lets load up prefixfree to handle CSS3 vendor prefixes -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/prefixfree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- You can download it from http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/ -->

<!-- Time for jquery action -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I have seen this solution, But i need the design to be exactly like the screenshot I have posted... I am just having trouble is with trapezoid like structure in the middle.